# Exclude a result by ID from search in elasticsearch-php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

**I was trying something like:**

```
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must_not']['id']['value']=$pid;
```

But it doesn't work. Need some help for the correct syntax please.

**full code:**

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$params = array();
$params['index'] = 'xyz';
$params['type'] = 'product';
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['and'][]['term']['userid'] = $uid;
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['and'][]['term']['categoryid3'] = $pc;
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must_not']['id']['value']=$pid;
$params['size'] ='5';
$result = $client->search($params);
```

**Updated full code**

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$params = array();
$params['index'] = 'xyz';
$params['type'] = 'product';
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['and'][]['term']['userid'] = $uid;
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['and'][]['term']['categoryid3'] = $pc;
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['not'][]['ids']['values'] = [$pid];
$params['size'] ='5';
$result = $client->search($params);
```

Instead of excluding that result with the pid, now it is showing only that result.

NOTE:  Figured it out myself..Added in the answer section

Comment: i want to exclude a result from search for that specific $pid. The search result won't show that id values.

Comment: do you want to exclude '_id ' field from the result..??

Comment: not only the _id field, the whole result for that id. The search result should not include any data from that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html
,for combining mutiple filters all needs to be under bool filter.

So it worked after i changed all to :

```
 $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['term']['userid'] = $uid;
 $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['term']['categoryid2'] = $pc;

 $params['body']['query']['bool']['must_not'][]['ids']['values'] = [$pid];
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct query for that is [`ids`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) not `id`

```
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must_not']['ids']['values'] = [$pid];
                                                ^         ^     ^    ^
                                                |         |     |    |
                                             fix this and this and this
```

Besides your query is ill-formed, it should be

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['not'][]['ids']['values'] = [$pid];
```

Comment: *67 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response
[status code] 400
[reason phrase] Bad Request
[url] http://localhost:9200/restored_index_lelongoct/product/_search' in /usr/local/openresty/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php:43

Comment: Try enclosing $pid in an array `... = [$pid]`

Comment: umm my bad...actually it didn't work. It is now only showing result for that id. it's like the 'not' is considered as 'and'

Comment: Please update your question again (e.g. Update 2) with the current code you have now?

Comment: fixed it, after i put them all under [bool] section

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$pid = 25;
$params = array();
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must_not']['id']['value']=$pid;
```